# calling third party c functions from python

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I have a requirement of calling third party c functions from inside python.
To do this I created a c api which has all the python specific c code ( using METH_VARARGS) to call the third party functions. I linked this code liba.so with the 3 party library libb.so
In my python file , I'm doing:

```
import liba *
```

Python now complains libb.so not found.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to include `liba.so` in your PATH, otherwise Python won't know where to look for it.

Try the following code, it'll load the library if it can find it from PATH, otherwise it'll try loading it from the directory of the load script

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.util import find_library
import os


if find_library('a'):
    liba = CDLL(find_library('a'))
else:
    # library is not in your path, try loading it from the current directory
    print 'liba not found in system path, trying to load it from the current directory'
    print '%s/%s'%(os.path.dirname(__file__),'liba.so')
    liba = CDLL(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'liba.so'))
```

http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#finding-shared-libraries

**UPDATE:** I was wondering why you created a native library (`liba`) to access a native 3rd party library (`libb`). You can import the third party c library straight into python using `ctypes` and create a python (not native) wrapper for `libb`. For instance to call the standard c lib `time` you would do

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> lib_c = CDLL("libc.so.6")
>>> print lib_c.time(None)
1150640792
```

and for libb

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> lib_b = CDLL("libb")
>>> lib_b.hello_world(None)
```

Comment: I made sure liba.so and libb.so are both in my path . Still have the same problem. libb.so ( 3rd party library)not found

Comment: It is able to find liba.so .. but complains about libb.so which is linked with liba.so. I made sure that libb.so is also in the path

Comment: So if you do `CDLL(find_library('b'))` it works? Also noticed that you're importing `liba` slightly strangely, you should either do `import liba` or `from lib import *` not `import liba *` the latter is invalid syntax  
`

Comment: The 3rd party function calls are too complex and my api is designed to shield the python user from that.

Comment: Also I tracked the problem to the dlopen where it tries to resolve all the symbols. I want the dlopen to be in the RTLD_LAZY mode. I guess I can do that only via ctypes(lib_name. mode=1). Is there a way to do it via the import statement ?

Comment: It says in the Python docs that `RTLD_LAZY` is the default mode for `dl.open` http://docs.python.org/library/dl.html#dl.open. I'm happy to help you debug this, but I think I would need some example code for `libb` and `liba` to move forwards.